# Keep background image at constant height relative to header

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

The image in the second row is being pushed down and away from the header above it as you resize the window. It should remain at a constant distance from the header right above it, but also stay attached to the bottom of its row.

**HTML**

```
    <div class="row hero-family">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
        <div class="container blurb">
          <h1 class="header">Nice big title here</h1>
          <p>More lorem ipsum text. How can I keep the image below at a constant distance from this header, while keeping it attached at the base of this row as well?</p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-red">Big long button here</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row hero-family family-image">
      </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.hero-header h2 {
    margin: 108px 0 30px 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 58px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #000;
    width: 43%;
    line-height: 80px;
}
.hero-header p {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 40%;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    padding-bottom: 36px;

}
.hero-unit {
  background-image: url("/../images/bg.png");
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 584px; */
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .hero-header h2, .hero-header p{
    width: 80%;
  }
}
.hero-header {
    margin-left: -15px;
}
@media (max-width: 540px) {
  .hero-unit {
    height: auto;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .hero-unit .pull-left {
    display: none;
  }
  .hero-unit .call-us {
    margin-top: 6%;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .hero-unit .fa-phone {
    color: #000;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 376px) {
  .hero-unit .call-us {
    display: none;
  }
  .hero-unit .pull-left {
    display: block;
  }
}
.hero-unit .hero-header {
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.family-image {
  background-image: url("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ftp-site-images/family.png");
  background-color: #eee;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center bottom;
  height: 500px;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .family-image {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .family-image {
    margin-bottom: 10%;
  }
}

.hero-family {
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: #eee;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .hero-family {
    height: 250px;
  }
}
.hero-family .blurb {
  text-align: center;
  width: 76%;
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  .hero-family .blurb {
    margin-left: -1%;
  }
}
.hero-family .header {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #ce2523;
  margin: 6%;
  font-size: 53px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .hero-family .header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .hero-family .header {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}
.hero-family p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  text-align: center;
  margin: -3%;
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .hero-family p {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
  }
}
.hero-family .btn-red {
  margin-top: 6%;
  font-weight: 400;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .hero-family .btn-red {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
.hero-header h2, .hero-header p {
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
}
```

**JSFIDDLE: [LINK](https://jsfiddle.net/mtd4rpkd/5/)**

Comment: you may look at vmax or vmin units https://jsfiddle.net/mtd4rpkd/6/ or set height in wh or vw units  see https://web-design-weekly.com/2014/11/18/viewport-units-vw-vh-vmin-vmax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the image scales with the viewport, it will not be a fixed height, but you have a fixed height on the element that it's a background image of. You need to use a relative inner padding to match the aspect ratio of the image.

Remove `height: 500px` from `.family-image` and add `padding-bottom: 42.6%` (1095 / 2570 * 100)

https://jsfiddle.net/mtd4rpkd/7/

```css
.hero-header h2 {
    margin: 108px 0 30px 0;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 58px;
    font-weight: 100;
    color: #000;
    width: 43%;
    line-height: 80px;
}
.hero-header p {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 300;
    width: 40%;
    color: #000;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    padding-bottom: 36px;
    
}
.hero-unit {
  background-image: url("/../images/bg.png");
  width: 100%;
  /* height: 584px; */
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
@media (max-width: 991px){
  .hero-header h2, .hero-header p{
    width: 80%;
  }
}
.hero-header {
    margin-left: -15px;
}
@media (max-width: 540px) {
  .hero-unit {
    height: auto;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .hero-unit .pull-left {
    display: none;
  }
  .hero-unit .call-us {
    margin-top: 6%;
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .hero-unit .fa-phone {
    color: #000;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 376px) {
  .hero-unit .call-us {
    display: none;
  }
  .hero-unit .pull-left {
    display: block;
  }
}
.hero-unit .hero-header {
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.family-image {
  background-image: url("https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/ftp-site-images/family.png");
  background-color: #eee;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center bottom;
  /*height: 500px;*/
  padding-bottom: 42.6%;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .family-image {
    height: 300px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .family-image {
    margin-bottom: 10%;
  }
}

.hero-family {
  background-color: #eee;
  background-color: #eee;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .hero-family {
    height: 250px;
  }
}
.hero-family .blurb {
  text-align: center;
  width: 76%;
}
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation: portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1) {
  .hero-family .blurb {
    margin-left: -1%;
  }
}
.hero-family .header {
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #ce2523;
  margin: 6%;
  font-size: 53px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .hero-family .header {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 28px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .hero-family .header {
    font-size: 36px;
  }
}
.hero-family p {
  font-family: 'Open Sans';
  text-align: center;
  margin: -3%;
  font-size: 18px;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .hero-family p {
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 10px 0 10px;
  }
}
.hero-family .btn-red {
  margin-top: 6%;
  font-weight: 400;
}
@media (max-width: 400px) {
  .hero-family .btn-red {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 768px){
.hero-header h2, .hero-header p {
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="hero-unit">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="container hero-header">
      <h2>Title text goes here, for you to read</h2>
      <p>This is a bunch of lorem ipsum text to fill up space that will eventually be taken over by real content. Just filler content here, but it seeps into the row below is when resizing.</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-ghost pull-left">contact us</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-ghost call-us">call us 24/7 <i class="fa fa-phone"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-6">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="row hero-family">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">
    <div class="container blurb">
      <h1 class="header">Nice big title here</h1>
      <p>More lorem ipsum text. How can I keep the image below at a constant distance from this header, while keeping it attached at the base of this row as well?</p>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-red">Big long button here</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row hero-family family-image">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fix:
                 You have to just remove background-position from class .family-image also set height 257px to the class it will fix your issue